# Default ngModel in angular directive not being set

Tags: angularjs

I have this custom directive in angular that looks like this: (removed most of the code for brevity).

```
angular.module("SharedModule")
    .directive('singleSelect', ['$ionicModal', singleSelect]);

function singleSelect($ionicModal) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace:true,
        template: [
            '<div class="item item-icon-right" ng-click="showItems($event)" >',
            '{{text || headerText}}',
            '<i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>',
            '</div>'
        ].join("")
        ,
        scope: {
            items: "=",
            headerText: "@"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {

            if (ngModelController.$modelValue){ // i even tried $viewValue here
                scope.selectedItemId = ngModelController.$modelValue.id;
                scope.text = ngModelController.$modelValue.text;
            }
            scope.change = function (item) {
                ngModelController.$setViewValue(item);
                scope.text = ngModelController.$viewValue.text;
                scope.close();
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I set the default for the ng-model as:

```
<single-select ng-model='defaultValue' header-text='text when no default present'>
```

and setting the value for `defaultValue` to `{id:"1",label:"foo"}` in the scope.

I expect that my template shows a `foo` when rendering my directive template but it does not. Debugging shows that my ngModel values are set to NaN. I am sure i am missing something trivial here. What could it be?

Also, how could i display my ngModel's `label` value in the template without an intermediate scope property like the `text` i have used.

UDPATE: i have created a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asadpalekar/PdCCE/7/) to explain the problem well.
I expect my div to display `foo` in the jsfiddle and not the default text.

Comment: none of the isolated scope properties appear as attributes in the html. Hard to figure out what you are doing here. Suggest you create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) demo

Comment: I have removed the code consuming `items` for brevity. What it does is gives the user an options to select a value from within the items list. The `change` function sets the ngModel value properly and hence i believe my bindings for `items` work correctly. It also updates my `text` value in the template. My question lies during the initialisation of the directive wherein i set a default value for the ngModel.

Comment: @charlietfl : added a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

if you replace you make you set your header text as follows foo will appear `header-text={{defaultValue.text}}` and remove ng-model, you can use angular's default templeting system

I've included a full JSfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/0Lpy7gff/